# Choosing the right N in $\epsilon-N$ proof

Tags: real-analysis

I'm just a little bit confused in choosing the right $N$ when working on the rough sketch of the proof. Suppose after some algebra we have reached the point where we get this expression, say:

$\frac{13}{4n+10} < \epsilon$

We can then set n > $\frac{13-10\epsilon}{4\epsilon}$ to get the right definition at the end if $n>N$.

However, can't we also choose $n > \frac{13}{4\epsilon}$, because $\frac{13}{4\epsilon} > \frac{13-10\epsilon}{4\epsilon}$ for each $\epsilon > 0$?

Or further, how about $n > \frac{8}{\epsilon}$? Which of this alternative is then the acceptable way to do the proof? There seems to be tons of alternatives once we know 'the minimum right value of N'.

Thanks

Comment: The short answer is that any $n$ works as long as it is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Well, you just answered your question. Once you know the minimum value of $N$ it doesn't really matter after that point. Choose whichever you want, they are all correct. That is, mathematically speaking at least. In a standard calculus course, I would choose the minimum value (or the minimum value +1) usually, so that the instructor will realise you understand the steps, and you are not just randomly guessing some huge values.

Comment: Ok thanks, yes I'm currently doing real analysis course.